# Invalid Token Error when using authentication middleware

Tags: authentication, jwt

I want to update a specific user based on their id and I am using authorization with this middleware.

This is my isAuth.ts middleware:

```
<blink>
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from '../models/User';

const authMiddleware = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header('Authorization')?.replace('Bearer ', '');
    console.log(token);

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    console.log('this is the secret',secret);

    if (!secret) {
      throw new Error('JWT secret is not defined');
    }
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret, { ignoreExpiration: true }) as { userId: string,exp: number };


    console.log('this is the decoded',decoded);

    const user = await User.findById(decoded.userId);
    console.log('this is the user', user);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
    res.locals.user = user;

    next();
  } catch (err:any) {
    console.log(err.message);

    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
};

export default authMiddleware;
</blink>
```

When testing with postman, I got 'Internal server error' and when I logged the error, i got: invalid token even after checking the secret JWT in my .env file and after checking the expiresIn but when I logged the decoded, it is not logging anything one the console. I tried everything but it did not work and the token is still invalid. Can anyone tell me if something is wrong with the verify() method or is something else causing the error?

Comment: And what's the exact output of this line: `console.log(token);` ?

Comment: This line logs nothing to the console, it is like it does not exist. However an error is being logged 'Invalid token'

Comment: Here is what has been logged to the console: 'Connected to MongoDB
Server listening at http://localhost:5356
"the correct token is logged in here"
this is the secret <my-secret>
invalid token'

Comment: If `token` is empty, it's logical that `jwt.verify(token,...` considers it an 'Invalid token'. But that means, you did not send a token.

Comment: I don't think the token is empty, besides, I sent it on the authorization as it should be sent, however the error persists!

Comment: I asked you to tell me the result of `console.log(token);`  and you replied that it *logs nothing to the console*, but now you write *I don't think the token is empty*?

Comment: Aww, sorry I thought you asked about the decoded LOL, actually the token is logged just fine but the problem is in the decoded value, I guess in the verify().

Comment: Besides if i did not send a token then postman's response will be 'Unauthorized' not 'Internal server error'